# Expand margins of ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

Apologies for the simplistic question, but I'm having trouble adjusting the size (width) of this plot to include all the data so that it doesn't look so squished. I've tried adjusting the margins and the width in png(), but nothing seems to work.

```
png("file_name.png",  units = "in", width = 10, height = 5,  res = 300)

ggplot(pred, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Fitted)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ CYR) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = 'plasma',
                     na.value = 'transparent') +
  coord_quickmap() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
  # theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,20,0,20), "mm"))

dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use `coord_quickmap()` for some reason? Removing it 'fixes' the plot dimensions, e.g. using the [palmerpenguins dataset](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

p1 <- ggplot(penguins, aes(x = sex,
                     y = bill_length_mm,
                     fill = bill_depth_mm)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'plasma',
                       na.value = 'transparent') +
  facet_wrap(~interaction(island, species, year)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top') +
  coord_quickmap()

p1
#> Warning: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted
#> ℹ Consider using `geom_tile()` instead.
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_raster()`).
```

[image]

```r
p2 <- ggplot(penguins, aes(x = sex,
                     y = bill_length_mm,
                     fill = bill_depth_mm)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'plasma',
                       na.value = 'transparent') +
  facet_wrap(~interaction(island, species, year)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top') #+
#  coord_quickmap()

p2
#> Warning: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted
#> ℹ Consider using `geom_tile()` instead.
#> Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_raster()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow, feeling dumb. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome, and there is nothing 'dumb' about your question - ggplot can be very frustrating when something 'goes wrong', but it's phenomenal software when things 'go right'. I've been trying to improve by watching people like https://www.cedricscherer.com/tags/ggplot2/; if you have time it's worth seeing the 'right way' to do things